# What is the meaning of "Sine wave energy per pulse" when referring to thyristors?

Tags: switching, thyristor

I am looking at the datasheet of a Westcode thyristor (specifically, the  R3968), and it has the following graph:

[image]

I am wondering if someone can explain to me what the graph is showing me! I don't understand the meaning of "sine wave energy per pulse."

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The graph gives the energy dissipated in the device for each pulse of current where the shape of the pulse is a half sine wave. The current marked on each curve is probably the peak on-state current per pulse. Perhaps the Westcode literature will confirm.

Comment: Interesting... That clears it up, thank you.  Do you know if there is a benefit to triggering a thyristor with a half sine wave vs a normal rectangular function?

Comment: The curves are about current pulses conducted from anode to cathode, not trigger pulses. The trigger pulses need to be rectangular. The current pulse through the thyristor is shaped by external circuitry.

Comment: Thanks again. This graph seems a little ambiguous.  So, please correct me if I'm wrong:
This graph shows the entire loss experienced by the thyristor for different sine-wave frequencies/periods (x-axis), at specific peak currents?  For example, for a 50Hz sine wave (1e-2s, for half)  of peak 1kA, there will be 10J of loss (assuming that the thyristor conducts for the entire half-sine wave).  Would this include the turn-on/-off losses?

Again, thanks a lot! Wasn't taught this in school...

Comment: It is only for high frequency. It is not for 50 Hz to 400 Hz. For that you would look at the curves that give losses at various conduction angles and on-state current. There should also be loss curves for rectangular pulses of current over a wide frequency / pulse-width range. The explanation is in the GE SCR Manual, 5th ed 1972. It is not presented exactly the same way, but it is basically the same thing.

Comment: Why wouldn't this graph apply to to 50Hz, if the information is given for 1e-2s (which should correspond to the 50Hz case)? Would this at least be true for a conduction angle of 0?

Comment: I agree; it should apply to delay angle of zero or conduction angle of 180 degrees for the range it covers. The GE manual just says that the 50-400 Hz curves are not for high frequency, not the other way around. If you want to look at the GE manual, it can be found online.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Charles. :)  You helped me to understand.

Answer (score 0):

The energy per pulse is the energy loss in the thyristor during a pulse with the given shape (a half sine wave) and duration (in milliseconds) and peak current (in amperes).

For example, a 1000A 1ms pulse will cause 1J of dissipation. If you repeat that at 1kHz you'll get 1000J/s or 1kW dissipation in the thyristor if Tj = 125°C.